# Displaying python output to website

Tags: python, html

I can print my output in Powershell but I want the text to be displayed on the website, not on the Powershell.

Here is my index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fluxus Generator</title>
</head>

<body bgColor="peachpuff">
  <center><h1>Fluxus Generator</h1><center>

    <center><img src="card.png" alt="Card" /></center>
    <font face= "Calibri" size="7" color = "purple">

  <center><p><a href="/">Another Card</a></p></center>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is app.py: (I united app.py with main.py since separately didn't work)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import random

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

def generate_word():
    """Generate a list of words and shuffle them"""
    words = list()

    req = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plain_English_words_and_phrases')
    html_source = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, "html.parser")

    for source in soup.find_all('a', { "class" : "extiw" }):
        word = source.find(text = True)
        try:
            word = str(word)
            words.append(word)
        except:
            pass

    random.shuffle(words)
    return words


def generate_instruction(words):
    """Build an instruction from the word lists"""
    instruction_struct = [
        'I', words[0], words[1], words[8], 'the',
        words[2], words[5], 'with',
        words[4], words[7]
    ]

    instruction = ' '.join(instruction_struct)
    print instruction


words = generate_word()
generate_instruction(words)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I've tried cgi, web but didn't work out.
How should I change the code so I get the text on my website?
Should I add to index.html?

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work out?"

Answer (score 0):

`BeautifulSoup` is a wrong tool here. It's for parsing of pages, and what you need is an inverse, creation of a page.

What you need is a *templating engine*, such as Jinja2 (large) or Tempita (tiny).

With it, you create a HTML *template*, a document with a normal structure and a few placeholders, then *render* it by replacing the placeholders with data.

(Flask is a good choice. For even fewer dependencies, try [web.py](http://webpy.org/).)